# Castle factory for short living dependencies

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, factory

I need my singleton service to depend on per web request object, and I would like to use Castle's TypedFactoryFacility to create automatically factory for my objects.

My registration looks like this:

```
        kernel.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
        kernel.Register(
            Component.For<IMailMessageQueueProvider>()
                .AsFactory()
            );

        kernel.Register(
            Component.For<IMailMessageQueue>()
                .ImplementedBy<MailMessageQueue>()
                .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest
            );
```

I also registered Per Web request life time in web.xml, factory interface looks like this:

```
    public interface IMailMessageQueueProvider
    {
        IMailMessageQueue Get();
    }
```

And I getting this nice error:

```
Type Model.IMailMessageQueueProvider is abstract.
As such, it is not possible to instansiate it as implementation of service        
Model.IMailMessageQueueProvider.
```

Why Castle is not creating factories?

this is a reference which I followed: http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx

Comment: Just for kicks, try renaming the `Get` method to something else (`BuildCreateMailMessageQueue` or something like that)

Comment: I'm using 2.5, tried with other names earlier: Create() and GetIMailMessageQueue(), I could try others...

Comment: Hmm. Can't really say it makes sense. If you're sure you add the facility *before* registering the component it ought to work. Does it happen in v3 too?

Comment: I tried different names and created dummy class with factory 1:1 as was in the example (which means without any dependencies and with default lifestyle) http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx, and it still not working, tomorrow I will try this with clean project (nerd dinner or something) with libraries which I'm using and then with v.3. I will write how it worked

Comment: It is not working in aforementioned scenarios. However I think I found what is not working. It seems that TypedFactoryFacility doesn't work with micro kernel, when I switched from IKernel kernel = new DefaultKernel(); kernel.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>(); to version with installers it started to work. My guess is that TypedFactoryFacility needs kernel to have support for dynamic proxies. I already know that kernel construtor can take proxy factory dependency. Is there any default implementation for this factory? I cannot find this to check my guess.

Comment: ok, I got it : IKernel kernel = new DefaultKernel(new DefaultProxyFactory());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found what I was missing. I was using Micro kernel with default implementation:

```
IKernel kernel = new DefaultKernel();
```

which was missing dynamic proxy support. There are two solutions, either stick with micro kernel and add dynamic proxy factory dependency:

```
IKernel kernel = new DefaultKernel(new DefaultProxyFactory());
```

or switch to [Castle Windsor Container](http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/trunk/concepts/choosing.html).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than create a specific factory (e.g. your IMailMessageQueueProvider) for each type you want to instantiate, a slicker approach might be to create one generic factory:-

```
public interface IServiceFactory
{
    T Create<T>();
    void Release(object service);
}
```

Register it with Windsor in the usual way:-

```
container.Register(Component.For<IServiceFactory>().AsFactory());
```

Inject IServiceFactory into the class where you want to do your instantiation, then call the Create method. E.g.

```
var queue = _factory.Create<IMailMessageQueue>();
```